# RecyclerView not showing from inside dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-recyclerview, dialogfragment

In my android application, I have a fragment which opens a dialogfragment, which itself contains a recyclerview. I previously had a listview, but needed the horizontal scrolling functionality (note that the listview worked). getCount() returns 0, and as expected onBindViewHolder is never called. I therefore have an error at the stage when I call the adapter, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is. Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Snippet from dialogfragment :

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.feed_dialog, null);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    imageId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    imageId.add(R.drawable.sample_bag);
    imageId.add(R.drawable.sample_bag);

    RecyclerView listview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_dialog_listview);
    listview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    FeedImageDialogFragmentList adapter = new FeedImageDialogFragmentList(getActivity(), imageId);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
}
```

And my adapter class:

```
public class FeedImageDialogFragmentList extends      
        RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedImageDialogFragmentList.ViewHolder>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<Integer> imageId;

    public FeedImageDialogFragmentList(Activity context, ArrayList<Integer> imageId) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_feed_dialog, null, false);
        return new FeedImageDialogFragmentList.ViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedImageDialogFragmentList.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Integer item = imageId.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
        holder.image.setImageResource(item);

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_dialog_image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageId.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, its two years ago, did you ever find a reason for this ?